# Appium AndroidDriver sendKeys send text to last edited textbox even after scrolling down and sending text to the another field

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate salesforce native apps create contact page. I am able to click and input text in all field which are seen on android mobile's first page. But for other fields which I get after scrolling down the page, appium is able to find the field as seen from appium log, but while clicking and sending text, it always send to last edited textbox on first page.

Can please anyone let me know If there is something extra needed to send text after scrolling page with appium.

I am using Android samsung galaxy S3 device. Below is the code and UIAutomator screen shot.

```
package samsungGalaxy;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class FirstTest {
    AndroidDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "ce1d12134");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.salesforce.chatter");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.salesforce.chatter.Chatter");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.4.16.1");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void login() {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[contains(@resource-id,'home')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Contacts']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.salesforce.chatter:id/new_button")).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]/..//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Phone')]/../android.widget.EditText")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]/..//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Phone')]/../android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("5109651200");
        driver.hideKeyboard();
        driver.scrollTo("Mobile");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]/..//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]/../android.widget.EditText")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]/..//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]/../android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("6509651200");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    @AfterTest
    public void End() {
        driver.closeApp();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

[image: UIAutomator viewer pic]

I tried to just send the text to Mobile field using TouchAction also as below. In appium log it says success but on moble page neither click nor input happens.

```
driver.swipe(200, 1140, 250, 600, 4000);
    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]/..//android.widget.EditText"));
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
    touchAction.press(we);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    boolean displayed = we.isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Displayed :" + displayed);
    we.click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]/..//android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("6509651200");
```

[image: appiumInspectImage]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are specifying the same locator to send the keys after scrolling to an element as well. The statement

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]/..//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]/../android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("5109651200"); // or replace `Mobile` by `Phone`
```

is locating the same `android.widget.EditText` which probably is because of the XPath syntax you have used `/../`. Quoting from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), the Xpath syntax is as follows :

> ```
> nodename  Selects all nodes with the name "nodename"
> /         Selects from the root node
> //        Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are
> .         Selects the current node
> ..        Selects the parent of the current node
> @         Selects attributes
> ```

So you might want to change your code as :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Phone')]../android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("5109651200");
driver.hideKeyboard();  
driver.scrollTo("Mobile");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]../android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("6509651200");
```

> Note : In your case `../` and `..//` both shall work because of the
>   hierarchy of android classes in the app.

Comment: this xpath change didn't work and failed with org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS)

Comment: okay could you update the question with the `appium inspector` screenshot, so as to depict the XPath of either of these `EditText`

Comment: I am running app on real device and and connected to window laptop through USB. when I try to refresh appium it throws error as "error: No app set; ". so I am not able to get screen shot of app on appium inspector . appium inspector is always blank.

Comment: well if you could trace the XPath of the EditText that would help debugging the code

Comment: XPath i constructed on UI Automator viewer and I am using in code should be correct as similar XPath is working fine for Phone field which is visible in first page. Does appium inspector works on window machine with android device ?

Comment: added appium inspector screen shot. Its same as UI automator viewer.

Comment: what version of `appium` and `java-client` are you using?

Comment: Appium version is 1.4.16.1 and java-client is 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

User your code like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Phone')]//android.widget.EditText")).click();                                                                        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Phone')]//android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("5109651200");
driver.hideKeyboard();
driver.scrollTo("Mobile");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]//android.widget.EditText")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Create Contact Heading')]//android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Mobile')]//android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("6509651200");
```

Comment: This xpath change also didn't work and failed with org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Comment: @Sadik `android.view.View[contains(@content-desc,'Phone')]` and `android.widget.EditText` are at the same level it seems